# react-select change menu height

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to increase the menu height? I can decrease the height of menu with `maxMenuHeight` property. But i can't find a way to increase its height. I even tried `minMenuHeight` property but that couldn't do the trick. Here's my code along with custom styles:

```
const defaultStyles = {
        control: (base, state) => ({
            ...base,
        }),
        menu: base => ({
            ...base,
        }),
        menuList: base => ({
            ...base,
        })
    }

    const customStyles = {
        control: (base, state) => ({
            ...base,
            background: "#000000",
            // match with the menu
            borderRadius: state.isFocused ? "3px 3px 0 0" : 3,
            // Overwrittes the different states of border
            // Removes weird border around container
            boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
        }),
        menu: base => ({
            ...base,
            // override border radius to match the box
            borderRadius: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            // kill the gap
            marginTop: 0
        }),
        menuList: base => ({
            ...base,
            // kill the white space on first and last option
            padding: 0
        })
    }
```

```
<AsyncSelect
     className="basic-single"
     classNamePrefix="select"
     loadOptions={loadOptions}
     maxMenuHeight={500}
     isMulti
     styles={localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark' ? customStyles : defaultStyles}
     cacheOptions
     onChange={(e) => setSelect(e)}
     defaultOptions />
```

Comment: Is `Async` a control? And are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select library? And are you using typescript (tsx)?

Comment: Async is AsyncSelect actually. It is imported from the path `'/react-select/async'`. Yes i am using react-select package. And no i don't use tsx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with styles.

Change the

```
menuList: base => ({
    ...base,
})
```

with

```
menuList: base => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: "300px" // your desired height
})
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-rgb-7nzmb?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Well i tried your solution but it didn't work. that's weird

Comment: Did you check the demo?

Comment: Yes i checked it. And i can't understand what am i doing wrong. I literally copy and pasted your demo and yet i can't increase the height

Comment: Now i fixed it. Aparently the main container component must have a high height (in my case it was a card containing my select component)